# Make GET Request then display result in MessageBox C#

Tags: c#, api, get

I'm trying to utilize an api where i submit a GET request, and an example response would be something like:

```
{
  "status": true,
  "message": "Connected"
}
```

I know how to make the request, but how would I get for example a part of that response like the "status" and put into a variable or a label or a messagebox?

Comment: You need to parse that JSON into a .NET Object. The same way you would parse any other response.

Comment: Could I have an example? For example using Newtonsoft.Json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Install NewtonSoft from Nuget PackageManager.

Then you will be able to parse the JSON string based on your requirements

---

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;



public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string jsonstring = "{\"status\":true,\"message\":\"connected\"}";
         JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonstring); //this is thr string     
        string statusValue = (string)json["status"];
        MessageBox.Show("Status :"+statusValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it always better to parse into C# class like so `MyClass m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass >(jsonstring );`

Comment: Ah it works great! Thanks so much for taking the time to help me out :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class to model your JSON response:

```
public class Request
{
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize your JSON string with [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
var jsonstring = "{\"status\":true,\"message\":\"connected\"}";

var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(jsonstring);
```

Demo on [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KKHUZu).